# how to create a horizontal video viewing "heatmap" using Highcharts

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

Could someone point me in the right direction as to which type of chart to use to create a video viewing "heatmap" like the one shown here:

[image: example video heatmap image]

The idea is to show how a viewer has watched a video. In the image above, green = played; and layered oranged = rewatched.

Thanks in advance for any help.

I have access to the data, so I can format it in whatever means necessary. The sticking point seems to be the type of chart to render, so I'm starting there.

UPDATE: I've been able to create a demo by adapting one of the HighCharts heatmap demos – the limitation just seems to be vary the widths of the rectangles to represent different lengths of time. Demo here:

https://jsfiddle.net/alexpcoleman/88e55cfd/

Example data:

```
1970-01-01,0,0.4
1970-01-01,1,0.3
1970-01-01,2,0.1
1970-01-01,3,0.2
1970-01-01,4,0.7
1970-01-01,5,1.9
1970-01-01,6,2.6
1970-01-01,7,3.2
1970-01-01,8,2.7
1970-01-01,9,2.6
1970-01-01,10,2.9
1970-01-01,11,4.0
1970-01-01,12,5.1
1970-01-01,13,5.8
1970-01-01,14,6.3
1970-01-01,15,6.8
1970-01-01,16,8.7
1970-01-01,16.5,3.5
1970-01-01,18,7.4
1970-01-01,19,7.3
1970-01-01,20,7.0
1970-01-01,20.25,2.3
1970-01-01,20.75,9.3
1970-01-01,21,6.1
1970-01-01,22,5.6
1970-01-01,23,4.5
1970-01-01,50,2.5
1970-01-01,50.25,6.5
1970-01-01,51.25,9.5
1970-01-01,55,2.5
```

Highcharts JS from demo:

```
$('#stats_sessions').highcharts({

  data: {
    csv: document.getElementById('csv').innerHTML
  },

  chart: {
    type: 'heatmap',
    inverted: true
  },


  title: {
    text: 'Test Video Heatmap'
  },

  xAxis: {
    tickPixelInterval: 50,
    // min: Date.UTC(2015, 4, 1),
    // max: Date.UTC(2015, 4, 30)
  },

  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: null
    },
    labels: {
      format: '{value}:00'
    },
    minPadding: 0,
    maxPadding: 0,
    startOnTick: false,
    endOnTick: false,
    tickWidth: 1,
    // tickPositions: [0, 6, 12, 18, 24],
    // min: 0,
    // max: 23
    // tickPositions: [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60],
    min: 0,
    max: 150.5 // <- VIDEO LENGTH
  },

  colorAxis: {
    stops: [
      [0, '#3060cf'],
      [0.5, '#fffbbc'],
      [0.9, '#c4463a']
    ],
    min: -5
  },

  series: [{
    borderWidth: 0,
    // colsize: 24 * 36e5, // one day
    tooltip: {
      headerFormat: 'Temperature<br/>',
      pointFormat: '{point.x:%e %b, %Y} {point.y}:00: <b>{point.value} ℃</b>'
    }
  }]

});
```

Comment: Without more information, I would probably use a simple stacked bar. Each segment representing one unbroken period of the same status.

Comment: What does your data look like?

Comment: @jlbriggs I'm not sure a stacked bar would work though, because I essentially need *overlaid* bars that can appear at any point along the way. For example: person may have watched (in seconds) [0.0 - 5.5]; then scrubbed to and watched [20.5-40]; and then rewatched [2.5-5.5]. So I need a way to depict all of that.

Comment: In that case, I would use the *columnrange* series type - set the *inverted* property to true on the chart options, and provide the same x value to each data point. That should allow overlap. You'll need to make sure that the segments that need to be on top in each overlap have a higher index.  I would probably make one series per segment type.

Comment: Can you explain what each data point represents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your video has parameters like currentTime or durration. You can use them in your chart.

If I understand you correctly, you can make standard heatmap chart and update the points which x values are equal to your currentTime value. Because this currentTime is float number, I think that the simplest idea is to use Math.floor() to make an integer from this value:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_floor.asp

You can update your points inside timeupdate event listener callback function:

```
   video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
      if (Math.floor(currentTime) !== Math.floor(this.currentTime)) {
        currentTime = Math.floor(this.currentTime);
        if (series.data[currentTime - 1]) {
          value = series.data[currentTime - 1].value;
          if (!value) {
            value = 0;
          }
          series.data[currentTime - 1].update({
            value: value + 1
          })
        }
      }
    });
```

Here you can see an example how it can work:
http://jsfiddle.net/59s7ao0s/10/

Kind regards.

Comment: That looks _perfect_. Thank you!